# Dual spaces of cartesian products, direct sums and tensor products

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products

For any topological linear space $X$, let $X^*$ denote its dual space of continuous linear functionals.

Let $X \times Y$ denote the Cartesian product of two TVS's, and let $X \oplus Y$ denote their direct sum.

- Is there a characterization of the dual spaces $(X \times Y)^*$ and $(X \oplus Y)^*$ in terms of $X^*$ and $Y^*$?

Suppose furthermore that the topologies on $X$ and $Y$ are locally convex. Let $X \otimes_p Y$ denote the projective tensor product, and let $X \otimes_i Y$ denote the injective tensor product (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product#Tensor_products_of_locally_convex_topological_vector_spaces)). There is a natural map $X \otimes_p Y \to X \otimes_i Y$.

- Is there a characterization of the dual spaces $(X \otimes_p Y)^*$ and $(X \otimes_i Y)^*$ in terms of $X^*$ and $Y^*$?

Comment: For two (finitely many) spaces, the product and direct sum are isomorphic (also topologically). Generally, we have $$\left(\prod_{\alpha} X_\alpha\right)^\ast \cong \bigoplus_{\alpha} X_\alpha^\ast;\quad \left(\bigoplus_{\beta} Y_\beta\right)^\ast \cong \prod_\beta Y_\beta^\ast$$ so there is a simple characterisation for direct sums and products. Don't know about the tensor products.

Comment: Have you tried to search in Grothendieck's "Résumé de la théorie métrique des produits tensoriels topologiques". I think I saw something related there.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please give me a reference for your statement, that would help me a lot.